# C++ How to simply select three random words from a list

Tags: c++

I am making an application in C++Builder.  When I click on a button, it should generate three words. How would I achieve this?

Here is my code so far:

```cpp
void __fastcall TForm1::onevClick(TObject *Sender)
{
    #include <iostream>
    #include <string>
    #include <cstdlib>
    #include <ctime>
    
    const string SndList[5] = { "Raid", "Moscow", "Express", "Express", "Garrison"};
    
    maps1 ->Text =
}
```

edit would this work

```
void __fastcall TForm1::onevClick(TObject *Sender)
{

    char Snd[5] = {"Raid","Moscow","Express","Express","Garrison"};
    maps1 ->Text = shuffle(Snd.begin(), Snd.end(), 3);
}
```

i get a excess elements in char array initilizer

Comment: That's easier, as it's not an `std::list`.  Search the internet for "C++ generate uniform random number".  Generate three random numbers between 0 and the length of the array.  Use the numbers as indices into the array.

Comment: What C++ resource are you using that states to use `#include` inside a method?  Common convention is to place them at the top of the source or header file.

Comment: Helpful: [`std::shuffle`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/random_shuffle). Then after shuffling the list, print out the first three items.

Comment: Thomas these are at the top I lazily copied them into this so i could also include my includes without coping everything else

Comment: When constructing an example, do everything in your power to make it a real representative example. If you don't you run the risk of people addressing the wrong problem. Use [mre] as inspiration.

Comment: when you need to pick 3 distinct elements, dont roll three times a number in [0,4], but instead roll one number in [0,4] another in [0,3] and the last in [0,2], in this way you never need to reroll to pick 3 different elements

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818 that could still pick the same item multiple times. You would have to remove/ignore the selected item from the set used in the next roll

Comment: @RemyLebeau yes, I don't know whats the best way to do it, so I left it for the reader ;). I suppose shuffling and taking the first 3 is simpler, I just don't know whats the replacement for `std::shuffle`

Comment: the includes are inside the function?

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818 "*I just don't know whats the replacement for `std::shuffle`*" - why replace it? It is a standard function since C++11.

Comment: @RemyLebeau oh wow, I got confused by two of the overloads being removed in C++17 (and not for the first time)

Answer (score 2):

Using `<cstdlib>` and `<ctime>`, you can use `std::rand()` (or, you can use C++Builder's own [`System::Random()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Random) function), eg:

```cpp
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
// or: #include <System.hpp>

__fastcall TForm1::TForm1(TComponent *Owner)
    : TForm(Owner)
{
    std::srand(std::time(0));
    // or: System::Randomize();
}   

void __fastcall TForm1::onevClick(TObject *Sender)
{
    System::String SndList[5] = { "Raid", "Moscow", "Express", "Express", "Garrison"};
    int count = 5;

    System::String words[3];

    for(int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
    {
        int index = std::rand() % count;
        // or: int index = System::Random(count);

        words[i] = SndList[index];

        for(int j = index + 1; j < count; ++j) {
            SndList[j-1] = SndList[j];
        }

        --count;
    }

    // use words[] as needed...
}
```

Or, if you are using one of C++Builder's [clang-based compilers](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Clang-enhanced_C%2B%2B_Compilers) then you can use the [`std::shuffle()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/random_shuffle) algorithm and [random-number generators](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random) that were introduced in C++11, eg:

```cpp
#include <random>
#include <algorithm>

void __fastcall TForm1::onevClick(TObject *Sender)
{
    System::String SndList[5] = { "Raid", "Moscow", "Express", "Express", "Garrison"};

    std::random_device rd;
    std::mt19937 gen(rd());

    std::shuffle(SndList, SndList+5, gen);

    System::String words[3] = { SndList[0], SndList[1], SndList[2] };

    // use words[] as needed...
}
```

Comment: But is there anyway to makee that generate 3 words instead of just the one

Comment: Obviously, you would just have to call the chosen random function 3 times instead of 1 time

Comment: How would one go about doing that? im new to coding

Comment: @Christopher I have updated my answer

Comment: @Remmy Lebeau How would I attach that to a label ? And will this code repeat the words? Because I don’t need them to repeat

Comment: @Christopher Something like `Label1->Caption = words[0] + " " + words[1] + " " + words[2];` As for repeatig words, your original example does have `"Express"` in the list twice, so it has the *potential* of getting repeated in the final output, if those 2 elements are both selected. If you don't want that, then filter out duplicates from the list beforehand.